# Как изначально включить плагин в тему Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как подключить плагин ACF со всеми настройками, которые я производил в тему Wordpress, чтобы при установке данной темы на другом сайте данный плагин активировался и потянул за собой предустановленные мной настройки полей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Добавьте в function.php

```
 function run_activate_plugin( $plugin ) {
     $current = get_option( 'active_plugins' );
     $plugin = plugin_basename( trim( $plugin ) );

     if ( !in_array( $plugin, $current ) ) {
     $current[] = $plugin;
      sort( $current );
      do_action( 'activate_plugin', trim( $plugin ) );
      update_option( 'active_plugins', $current );
      do_action( 'activate_' . trim( $plugin ) );
      do_action( 'activated_plugin', trim( $plugin) );
     }

    return null;
  }
run_activate_plugin( 'contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php' );
run_activate_plugin( 'advanced-custom-fields/acf.php' );
run_activate_plugin( 'akismet/akismet.php' );
```

> Экспорт/импорт параметров ACF:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хорошо, ACF я подтяну, а как сделать так, чтобы он захватывал за собой желаемые настройки?

Comment: При активации плагин автоматически включает настройки которые вы указали.  Если же сайт новый без старой БД необходимо делать экспорт/импорт полей   https://github.com/iamntz/acf-recovery

Comment: а том же functions.php нельзя указать, чтобы после установки брал определенные настройки?

Comment: Можно, в статье  описан вариант.

Comment: Плагин ACF позволяет делать экспорт всех групп поле в формате PHP   При экспорте есть мини инструкция как это делается,  вам нужно учесть  то что запускать нужно один раз.